# Looking for a specific CHAR element in a CHAR[] Array using a for loop = always False

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, char

So I'm doing homework, and it is supposed to be a game of cows and bulls.

I have generated 4 random integers to be guessed, and the user enters a 4 digit number. I then validate that the number is indeed 4 digits long and turn it into a array of CHARs. After that, I wanted to compare the randomly generated numbers one by one with the elements in the array, and if they are equal, add a "1" to a counter.

I have tried many solutions that I found on the internet to similar problems, some very difficult ones I have not as they seemed like overkill, because I am still very new to programming and I feel as though I am missing something simple and obvious. The problem is, everytime I iterate through the array, the elements should match, but the condition is always "False".

Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
    Scanner Sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(Sc1.hasNextInt()){                            // is it a number ? ?
        int user_guess = Sc1.nextInt();
        String user_guess_string = Integer.toString(user_guess);                  // how.
        int length = user_guess_string.length();                                   // many
        if(length != 4){                                                           //digits
            System.out.println("On vaja 4 numbrid.Mäng hakkab otsast pihta");
        cows_and_bulls();}

        char[] player_number = user_guess_string.toCharArray();  
        char num0 = (char)random1;  //  casting
        char num1 = (char)random2;  //  random numbers
        char num2 = (char)random3;   //  into
        char num3 = (char)random4;    //  chars
        int cows = 0;    // counter of instances where a number guessed by the user is in array
        int bulls = 0;  // counter of instances where a guessed number is in array and correct spot

        for (char element : player_number) {
            if (element == num0) {
                cows = cows + 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(cows);
        }

    else{ System.out.println("Not a number. Game will restart");
        cows_and_bulls();}

    }
```

---

I have also tried this :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            char c = Array.getChar(player_number,i);
            if (num0 == c) {
                System.out.println("works");
                break;
            }
        }
```

I know I am very bad at this, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` array is the wrong data structure, let's get rid of it. Adding magic numbers and casting is a code smell, I.E. `(char)(48 + random1)`.

From `Sc1.nextInt()` we know the input is an `int`, from `if(length != 4)` we know it's 4 characters long and we want a collection of `int` from it.

`char[] player_number = user_guess_string.toCharArray()` becomes:

```
List<Integer> player_number = Arrays.stream(user_guess_string.split(""))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, `char num0-3` can be changed to `int` and we're dealing with the datatypes we intended to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where are you getting `random1`, `random2`, `random3` and `random4` from as it's not part of the logic you pasted above but, the problem here is that you are not adding the ASCII of '0' i.e. `48` to the values above while casting them as characters.

Assuming that all the random numbers you have are valid digits in between `0 - 9`, the following should work.

```java
char num0 = (char)(48 + random1);
char num1 = (char)(48 + random2);
...
...
```